# How to convert log2 scale to normal scale in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

How to convert log2 transformed values back to normal scale in python 
Any suggestions would be great

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`log2(x)` is the inverse of `2**x` (2 to the power of x). If you have a column of data that has been transformed by `log2(x)`, all you have to do is perform the inverse operation:

```
df['colname'] = [2**i for i in df['colname']]
```

As suggested in the comment below, it would be more efficient to do:

```
df['colname'] = df['colname'].rpow(2)
```

[`rpow`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.rpow.html#pandas.Series.rpow) is a pandas Series method that is built in to the pandas package. The first argument is the base you'd like to take powers to. You can also use a `fill_value` argument, which is nice because you can tell it what to do if the result is `NaN`

Comment: Using built-in operation such as [rpow](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.rpow.html#pandas.Series.rpow) will most likely to be much faster than using a for loop:`df["col_name"] = df["col_name].rpow(2)`